# How do I use ROW_NUMBER in DB2 10 on z/OS?

Tags: db2, row-number, zos

I am running a SQL query and trying to break the results down into chunks.

```
select task_id, owner_cnum
    from (select row_number() over(order by owner_cnum, task_id)
        as this_row, wdpt.vtasks.*
            from wdpt.vtasks)
                where this_row between 1 and 5;
```

That SQL works with DB2 10.5 on Windows and Linux, but fails on DB2 10.1 on z/OS with the following error messages:

When I run the SQL from IBM DataStudio 4.1.1 running on my Windows machine connected to the database, I am getting:

```
ILLEGAL SYMBOL "<EMPTY>". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: CORRELATION NAME. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.18.60
```

When I run my Java program on a zLinux system connecting to the database, I get the following error:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=<EMPTY>;CORRELATION NAME, DRIVER=3.65.97
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some DB2 versions you must use a correlation name for a subselect, as suggested by the error message:

```
select FOO from (
  select FOO from BAR
) as T
```

Here "T" is the correlation name.